# Grails creates datetime column with unexpected extra precision

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have a lot of "Date" columns inside Domain objects that are previously created and associated with a DB column type "datetime"

But when I try to create a new column on this version it is "datetime(6)" - type with an extra precision.

To avoid this I have to define additional mappings such as

```
static mapping = {
   myDateColumn sqlType: "datetime", precision: 0
}
```

It seems that hibernate (or something else) version was changed and this led to a change in behavior.
The question is how to create a "Date" column without extra precision by default?

Env:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.16 
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7 
| JVM Version:    1.8.0_221 
| MySQL server: 5.7.27
| dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
| dbCreate: update
```